# Chartjs treemap example

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm currently using chart.js in my project and I have to say it's an amazing library. However I recently realised I also need a "treemap" which I was unable to find on their website.
Has anyone managed to implement a treemap example using chart.js?

Answer (score 10):

This snippet is an example of the [treemap](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) module for [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/).
Also here are [more examples](https://codepen.io/kurkle/full/JqbzgQ) and the [documentation](https://github.com/kurkle/chartjs-chart-treemap#readme).

```js
var topTags = [
  {tag:'python',num:133269},{tag:'javascript',num:109742},{tag:'java',num:65490},{tag:'c#',num:45445},{tag:'html',num:43767},{tag:'android',num:42657},{tag:'reactjs',num:38844},{tag:'php',num:34381},{tag:'sql',num:29996},{tag:'python',num:29942},{tag:'css',num:29654},{tag:'r',num:28319},{tag:'c++',num:27389},{tag:'node.js',num:25415},{tag:'angular',num:24093},{tag:'pandas',num:23826},{tag:'arrays',num:23075},{tag:'jquery',num:18968},{tag:'mysql',num:18863},{tag:'swift',num:17971},{tag:'ios',num:17600},{tag:'json',num:15589},{tag:'laravel',num:15537},{tag:'flutter',num:15201},{tag:'c',num:15195},{tag:'django',num:14748},{tag:'sql',num:12752},{tag:'reactjs',num:10974},{tag:'excel',num:10962},{tag:'list',num:10726},{tag:'regex',num:10676}
];

var canvas = document.getElementById("treemap");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var chart = window.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "treemap",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      tree: topTags,
      key: "num",
      groups: ['tag'],
      spacing: 0.5,
      borderWidth: 1.5,
      fontColor: "black",
      borderColor: "grey"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: { display: false },
    tooltips: { enabled: false }
  }
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-chart-treemap@0.2.3"></script>

<canvas id="treemap"></canvas>
```

Comment: Aaah! man thanks a lot. You saved the day. I already had the chart implemented i was having trouble setting the font color. Your example solved the problem for me. Thanks a lot. Also is there way to trunctuate or ellipse the text inside the columns if the text is long.

Comment: If you wanted to add the numbers underneath the label, i.e. "Python: 133269" how would you do that in this situation?